# table width to 100% with mdl but won't work

Tags: javascript, css, material-design

So i have the following code but when I try to fit the table on screen by using width 100% it doesn't work. But if i remove the mdl class from the table and its a normal html table then it works perfectly. Is there any way to fix this? I have the following CSS, HTML, and JS is on the jsfiddle website so it is easier for you guys to determine.

```
.full-width {
    width: 100% !important;
}

#removeTable{
  width: 100% !important;
}

<table id="createScheduleTable" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp full-width">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sphm1zxL/216/

Answer (score 0):

The input fields stay in one line because of the CSS style `white-space: nowrap;` in `mdl-data-table`. 
One of work around is :

```
<table id="createScheduleTable" style="white-space: normal;" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp full-width">
```